# How to edit airflow.cfg before running airflow db init?

Tags: airflow

When setting up Airflow, do I have to run `airflow db init` twice?

- Once with the default settings (SQL Lite etc.) in `airflow.cfg`
- Second time with my changes in `airflow.cfg`

It seems to cause errors when starting the services (webserver and scheduler).

I set up `AIRFLOW_HOME` folder

Running `airflow db init` will populate my `AIRFLOW_HOME` folder with a clean setup for Airflow, including `airflow.cfg` file.

Since I will use PostgreSQL instead of SQL Lite (default), I'm instructed
to do the following changes in `airflow.cfg`

```
executor = LocalExecutor

# under [database]
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@localhost/airflow
```

I ran `airflow db init` once after setting `AIRFLOW_HOME` and then after making the changes.

Now I get the following errors when running `airflow webserver`:

[image]

Comment: Did you run ariflow db reset before the second airflow db inti?

Comment: If you are planning to use postgres. It really isnt necessary to do an `airflow db init` initially. Simply when you install airflow and have postgres service running, change the `airflow.cfg` file and then do an `airflow db init`.